# $x, Ax, \cdots, A^mx, \cdots$ is not dense in $\Bbb R^n$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix, $x\in\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, dense-subspaces

> $x, Ax, \cdots, A^mx, \cdots$ is not dense in $\Bbb R^n$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix, $x\in\Bbb R^n$ are fixed.

This is a problem involving mathematical analysis and higher algebra. I have no idea.

1. Would we use the Jordan carnonical form, but the imaginary part seems trouble.
2. What about some orthogonal matrix $Q$ exists, such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is an upper block triangular matrix.

Comment: The subspace spanned by $x, Ax, ..., A^kx$ is called the $k$-Krylov subspace of $A$. The iterates tend towards the eigenvector to the eigenvalue of $A$ with the largest absolute value. I can't really help you with the wording of the question, but maybe the name of the construct helps you.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $A$ has a non-real spectrum. You may show that for any complex Jordan block $J$ and any complex vector $v$, $\{\|J^mv\|\}_{m\ge0}$ either converges or approaches infinity. It follows that $\{\|A^mx\|\}_{m\ge0}$ either converges or approaches infinity.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Then how to do?

Comment: @Laray Then how to do?

Comment: @user1551 First you said Jordan block, but for general $A$, there are blocks, and $x$ may effects the blocks simultaneously. So ...Then how to do?

Comment: @xldd By a change of basis, we may assume that $A$ is already in Jordan form $J_1\oplus\cdots\oplus J_k$. Partition $x$ according to the structure of this Jordan form and call the sub-vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. If $\{\|J_i^mx_i\|\}_{m\ge0}$ diverges for some $i$, then $\{\|A^mx\|\}_{m\ge0}$ diverges; if $\{\|J_i^mx_i\|\}_{m\ge0}$ converges for all $i$, then $\{\|A^mx\|\}_{m\ge0}$ converges.

Comment: @xldd I literally said, that I can't help you beyond the names the concepts...